# Fulltextsearch no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá! Tudo bem?

Preciso realizar uma consulta com o `fulltextsearch`, pois precisa ser indexado.
Porém, não estou conseguindo montar uma consulta que retorne todas as possibilidades, como se fosse um `like`.

A consulta que consegui montar é a seguinte

```
DECLARE @nmPessoa varchar(250)  

/*Exemplos de consultas*/
-- 1
--SET @nmPessoa = '1ª VARA  DE EXECUÇÃO FISCAL ESTADUAL - CURITIBA'
--2
--SET @nmPessoa = 'Curitiba'
--3
--SET @nmPessoa = 'Curi' 
--4
--SET @nmPessoa = 'FUMPISUL'
--5
--SET @nmPessoa = 'FUM'
--6
--SET @nmPessoa = 'CAMARA GRANDE'
--7
--SET @nmPessoa = 'FUMPISUL - FUNDO MUNICIPAL DE PREVIDÊNCIA DE PIRAÍ DO SUL'

    set @nmPessoa = '"*'+ @nmPessoa +'* "'  

    select p.nmPessoa
    from pessoa p       
    where CONTAINS(p.nmPessoa ,@nmPessoa)
```

No caso do 1ª exemplo, deverá retornar o registro exato (está correto)

No 2º exemplo todos os registros que possui 'Curitiba' na frase (está correto)

Já no 3º exemplo, deverá trazer as frases que possui 'Curi', ou seja, os registros de 'Curitiba' também devem aparecer (Não está funcionando)

E no exemplo 6, deverá trazer as frases que possui "Camara" e "Grande", mas não funciona, ele retorna as frases que tem 'Camara Grande',  como se ele fosse apenas 1 palavra.

A consulta utilizando `like` é esta, más eu não posso utilizar pois demora minutos para retornar. A quantidade de registros é grande.

```
DECLARE @nmPessoa varchar(250)  
DECLARE @parametro varchar(250) 
set @parametro = REPLACE( LTRIM(RTRIM(@nmPessoa)), ' ', '%')    
    select p.nmPessoa
    from pessoa p           
    where p.nmPessoa LIKE '%'+@parametro+'%'
```

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: O uso da função replace() no comando 
  set @parametro = REPLACE( LTRIM(RTRIM(@nmPessoa)), ' ', '%') 
gera valor de pesquisa incorreto, pois substitui todos os espaços por %. Inclusive os espaços entre palavras.
Por exemplo, "CAMARA GRANDE" se transforma em "CAMARA%GRANDE", resultando na busca por "LIKE '%CAMARA%GRANDE%'".

Comment: É exatamente isto @JoséDiz, quando a consulta é feita com 'like' ela retorna os resultados que necessito. O problema é que ela é muito lenta, demora minutos para trazer os resultados, mesmo limitando a quantidade.

Comment: @Luciane conhece o [full-text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? Me parece uma forma melhor para resolver seu problema

Comment: Olá @gmsantos, a primeira consulta que montei é full-text search, mas eu não consegui obter os mesmos resultados que obtinha quando era por like.